# ftpsync upload key binding in sublime text 2

Tags: file-upload, sublimetext2, sublimetext, key-bindings

i'm asking how to add a key binding for "Upload the file" of FTPsync, i just put this line in key bindings user in FTPSync but is not working:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+u"], "command": "ftp_sync_target" }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: I put the wrong command key binding is 'ftp_sync_current' instead 'ftp_sync_target'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That likely isn't the right command. In the ST console, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Then run the command like you would normally (without the key binding) and you should see the command to use. Alternatively, you can look at `Default.sublime-commands` or the key map file for the plugin to view the command to use.